# Camunda file bucket integration

Tags: file, spring-boot, camunda, minio

I'm using Camunda workflow and have to integrate file repository for reading stored workflows (.bpmn).I'm using docker container of minio server. So, are there any mechanisms to integrate file repository to camunda engine?.

Comment: Do you want to deploy from the filesystem repository or write definitions to the filesystem? in case you just want to write, I think approach mentioned by Jan would work, otherwise you could implement copy method from your filesystem repository to the folder available on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Camunda stores deployed processes in the database and since the complete engines relies on this, this won't be changeable to a file repo without a (complete) rewrite.

What you could do is to intercept the deployment and store the process in a file repo in addition to the database.

I did not do this before, but a good starting point should be the `ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl#getCustomPostDeployers(..)`, which allows to register code to be completed after the camunda deployment took place.